# can I compile a delphi xe2 with VBS code as a resource or dll

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a few things like running SFC, defrag, and reset the page file and so on, things that can be done within windows VBScript, I am just wondering if I can compile that code as a resource and call it as needed.  Thanks.

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) interfaces, `IActiveScript` and `IActiveScriptParse`, to execute Javascript/VBScript from memory.  You can then compile your Javascript/VBScript into a resource, extract it at runtime, and then execute it when needed.

**Update:** have a look at this blog article:

[Adding Active Scripting to your
Delphi Win32 application](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2007/06/13/36013)

And then look at this discussion to make it work in 64bit:

[Writing a scripting host in Delphi XE2 64-bit](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=67007)

Comment: Thank you for the response, you wouldn't happen to have an example of that technique?  Again thanks...

Comment: NOTE: from my experience it cannot be used inside your x64 application

Comment: Did you read the [Writing a scripting host in Delphi XE2 64-bit](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=67007) discussion? Is there a particular problem you are having in x64?